# C++ switch everything except

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have switch statement:

```
switch(str[index])
{
    case '0' ... '9': /* stuff */
}
```

is there a way to invert `case '0' ... '9'` to get ALL except symbols from 0 to 9?

Comment: Do nothing in this part, and then add a `default` clause to `switch` where you do stuff.

Comment: Consider that `switch` is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Perhaps you could just use `std::isdigit`.

Comment: This is a perfect example of an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/).  The solution is to use `isdigit()`, and not write a cumbersome `switch` statement.

Answer (score 2):

`case '0' ... '9'` does not work in C++, you have to use individual `case` statements instead.  Use fall-though to catch all digit cases, and then use a `default` case to handle everything else, eg:

```cpp
switch (str[index])
{
    case '0':
    case '1':
    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
        // do nothing...
        break;

    default:
        // everything else...
        break;
}
```

A better option is to use an `if` statement instead of a `switch`, eg:

```cpp
if (str[index] < '0' || str[index] > '9')
// or:
// if (!(str[index] >= '0' && str[index] <= '9'))
{
    // everything else...
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <cctype>

if (!std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(str[index])))
{
    // everything else...
}
```